# Unit testing in Django - where to draw the line?

Tags: django, unit-testing

I've been going through a lot of Django testing tutorials, but I'm a bit unsure as to how much to test. I'm primarily using classed based views

For instance, in testing my **views**, should I check all of the following:

- That every URL mapping is correct
- All views are using the expected template
- All views are using the expected form (if applicable)
- In every views that the expected context variables are there
- All posts redirect somewhere

Most of my views are class based views. I have a ListView, where I set the template_name, model and context_object_name. Should I be testing that these have been set correctly? There is no logic there so it seems a bit silly to test it since it is just configuration.

In testing **models**:

- Should I test that a validation error is raised when a field is marked as unique and I try to add another record with the same value for the field?
- If I add a MinValueValidator to a field, should I test that?
- I assume regex validators should be tested as there is logic there.

In testing **forms** (especially model forms)

- Should I check every field on a form that an error is generated for for invalid input?
- When an error is generated check the error message is correct?
- Test that a model forms saves an item correctly?
- There's tons of things that can potentially be testing for every field in the form, such as the help_text, place_holder etc.

A lot of these tests seems like I'm just testing configuration as opposed to logic. I know how to tests all the items as mentioned above, but when using class based views, the testing code can be 10x the amount of actuall code if I try to test everything.

So, my current idea is to test only places in my app where I add logic, not where it is only configuration. So if I override a method in a model form or in a view, I'll test that. Does this sound like a good approach or should I really be testing every little thing as mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to start with functional tests. They are for testing your entire stack, from the bottom up. For example, you have a model, a form, and a creation view. So you could have a test which just makes sure a user can open the creation form, and submitting that form results in the creation of an object. Just like a user does:

```
class CreationTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_creation_page_get(self):
        url = reverse('your_model_create')
        response = self.client.get(url)

        # Your page gave 200, so there are no severe configuration errors
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'your/template.html')
        # The template context contains your form, so most probably you view did fine.
        self.assertEqual(type(response.context['form']), YourForm)

    def test_creation_page_post(self):      
        payload = {'field1': 1, 'field2': 2}
        response = self.client.post(reverse('your_model_create'), payload)

        # Your page redirected to a success url, so the view did ok.
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('your-success-url'))
        # The instance is actually created and contains the right data
        instance = YourModel.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(instance.field1, payload['field1'])
```

Here we tested your urlconf, views, forms and models, by emulating user behaviour. Plus, you're free to change your underlying views and forms, keeping the same user workflow.

The biggest drawback of functional testing is speed. As you test your whole application, your testcase might take a lot of time.

Personally I tend to writing unit tests when I see the chunk of logic in the code I want to refactor, or it just *seems* to deserve testing.

In other words, test the behaviour, not the configuration.

Comment: Let's say the view is generated using a CreateView, where I only had to specify the model and the fields. Would you still recommend I test as per your example above? I guess if I don't set all the required fields it could lead to an error, so it probably makes sense to test.

Comment: Well, the tests should determine your system is usable by customers, not that the specific configuration values are set. If you don't set some of the required views field, the above test will fail as well. The benefit of this approach is that the test will fail too if you, say, broke your `form_valid()` and the object is actually not created. Plain testing of the class arguments just won't do the trick in this case.

Comment: Take also a look at the `django_webtest` module, which makes testing forms (required fields and stuff) a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!